# Redux-Form: Delete field data when specific option is selected

Tags: reactjs, forms, rest, httprequest, redux-form

I have an address form that has a United States option and an International option. When the U.S. option is selected a state drop down appears. When the International option is selected, the state drop down disappears.

My issue is when a state is selected, the form data for the state option doesn't get removed when the international option is selected and I do a POST to my service.

Is there a way for me to make sure an empty string is sent when international is selected, and not the previous data.

Below is the code for my radio group field to select U.S. or International.

```
             <Field
                component={RadioGroup}
                name={countryCodeName}
                choices={[
                    {
                        label: 'U.S. or U.S. Territory',
                        value: 'USA'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'International',
                        value: 'international'
                    }
                ]}
                label="Location"
            />
```

Below is the code for the state only on usa selection. I use formValueSelector from redux-form to accomplish this.

```
            {hasInternationalValue === 'USA' && (
                <Field
                    component={Select}
                    name={stateName}
                    label="State"
                    options={stateOptions}
                />
            )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by using Redux-Form's change() function.

change(form:String, field:String, value:String)
Saves the value to the field.

Inside the form:

```
this.props.changeFormValue('fieldValue', data);
```

Inside the container:

```
changeFormValue: (key, value) => {
    dispatch(change('formName', key, value));
}
```